# Query about JRockit Garbage Collection

Tags: oracle, garbage-collection, jrockit

I have a question about Oracle's JRockit 1.6. When I use genpar, does it select parallel for new generation or old generation or both.

In Sun JDK its only for young (unless you set UseParallelOldGC) ; I am trying to understand whether the same is true for JRockit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"genpar" uses parallel collection for both new and old generation.

See the description at: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15062/optionx.htm#i1011879